# How to calculate numbers upto thousand of digits

Tags: math, language-agnostic

Ho to do calculation on 32 bit computers with 2GB RAM.
When i do long number arithmetic then the programs start to give garbage value. But i want to do calculate numbers upto tens of thousands of digits.Any language is accepted.

Comment: Yes, for example in PHP you can use [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Java's [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), executes almost instantaneously:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class Int10k {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger  a, b, c;
        Random rnd;

        // Here I'll create two random 40,000-bit numbers (that's
        // rather more than 10,000 decimal digits) and add them
        // together. For specific numbers, you can use the
        // BigInteger(String) constructor, which creates a
        // BigInteger based on a String of digits.
        rnd = new Random();
        a = new BigInteger(40000, rnd);
        b = new BigInteger(40000, rnd);
        c = a.add(b);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("+");
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println("=");
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Esailija: On my system, `java Int10k > output` has a perceptible duration. If I remove the `System.out.println` lines it reduces that perceptible duration by about half, putting it *very near* the tolerance of my ability to perceive it. But I can percieve it... *just*. :-) Probably just JVM startup time, though, as opposed to the actual code.

Comment: Yes I just I realised it was the startup time, I removed my comment ;:P

Comment: @Esailija: Yeah, I just created a `DoNothing` class, it it looks exactly the same. So the actual code above is instantaneous by human standards (on my machine, ~3 GHz).

Comment: Personally, I rather dislike Java's `BigInteger` because you can't use the normal arithmetic operators.  It's much easier to use Python or .NET IMHO.

Comment: @TimS.: Yeah, well, Java doesn't have operator overloading (except that which is defined in the JLS -- e.g., the binary `+` being both an addition operator and a string concatenation operator).

Answer (score 3):

You may use Java BigInteger or any other Big Integer realization

Example:

```
BigInteger left = new Biginteger("1845618948745415218748");
BigInteger right = new BigInteger("1845452132132132123132123123");

out.println(left.add(right));
```

Comment: Yes, I sometimes use it on programming contest

Comment: For .NET it's [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). Also worth noting 10,000 decimal digits is about 33k bits, or around 4kB. This is not going to stress a system with RAM in GB... on a current system it should all sit in L1 cache for maximum speed.

Answer (score 3):

The library being used here is [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). It is included with PHP by default.

```
$big_int1 = "";
$big_int2 = "";

for( $i = 0; $i < 10000; ++$i ) {
    $big_int1 .= mt_rand(0,9);
    $big_int2 .= mt_rand(0,9);
}//0.019520044326 seconds or 20 milliseconds

echo bcadd( $big_int1, $big_int2 ); //0.00037407875061035 seconds or 374 microseconds
```

Executes instantly for me. The string concatenation/random number generation is the bottleneck anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some handy links for a variety of languages:

- [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) (built-in)
- C/C++ - [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), probably the most efficient general-purpose arbitrary-precision number library
- [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (built-in)
- .NET - [GnuMpDotNet](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/) - uses [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), so also very efficient, but with the benefit of being easier to work with due to operator overloading and such
- [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (built-in)
- PHP - [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a language problem, it's a Math problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic One which is both well known, and for which plenty of programming libraries exist to solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

All Common Lisp implementations include arbitrary-length integers. Typically the implementation punts to a C library to handle it, but it is more convenient to work in Lisp.

Take a look, for example, at Clisp, SBCL, or CMUCL (a web search will find home pages for those projects).

Answer (score 0):

With the question being as abstract as it is, yes, it is possible to implement such a calculator. At some point you may have to rely on disk caching and implementing the operations manually rather than relying on existing classes (e.g. Java's BigInteger), but it is technically doable.

Comment: -1: Why would you need disk caching? (A billion digit number needs less than 400MB: one decimal digit needs 1/(log 2) bits once in binary format. Here need add and subtract of only 10k digits: expect all to fit in L1 cache.)

Comment: @CodesInChaos log 10 == 1 because 10^1 == 10. Hence log(10)/log(2) == 1/log(2).

Comment: Oh you're using a convention where you use `log` for the base 10 logarithm. That's not the convention I'm used to, so I misread your post. We either use log as synonym for ln, or with a specific index to indicate the base.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: In computing texts the only convention I know where the base is not explicit: log -> base 10, ln -> natual, lb (rarer) -> binary.

Comment: @richard, `log2` is for binary in C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This is a public domain c++ library just for that: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Answer (score 0):

here is nice algorithm exists, you can use define 2 array [0-9] and according to each result, define a new array:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
/////
```

Then you can define an two dimensional array that put + result:

```
0 1 ....
1 ...
```

Same for * and / and etc, then you read a string type and create and string output.

Comment: And why would he choose such an inefficient implementation?